# Redirect output to printer via device file?

Tags: linux, printer, redirection, pipe

Is there a way in Linux to print a file with a modern printer (a Canon MX870 in my case) by redirecting text to a device file?

I imagine the command to look something like this:

```
cat my_notes.txt > /dev/printers/usb0
```

and then your printer to start printing on white paper.

I'm guessing it's not so simple, and not desired in this day and age but it would be a fun little trick to help someone learn about redirects, UNIX architecture and principles etc.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/options.html). I’m currently a little short on time and can’t explain in detail. Basically: `lp <filename>`

Comment: Oh, I didn't know the `lp` command used this abstraction. I assumed it breaks the abstraction to access more powerful printer features, since it's commonly used. I need to learn the basics before making assumptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print from a pipeline:

```
cat my_notes.txt | lpr
```

Of course, if you just want to print from a file from the command line:

```
lpr my_notes.txt
```

`lpr` applies the usual filters to format the output and then convert the result to the printer-specific hardware commands.

`lp` can be used in place of `lpr`.  Historically, `lp` was developed by AT&T while `lpr` was part of Berkeley BSD.  Both have similar capabilities and modern *nix systems make both available.

Comment: Thanks. The pipeline version was the one I was looking for.

Comment: June 2018 this was the first answer from Google.